# Count the divisors of a number

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, division

## Introduction

This is a very simple challenge: simply count the divisors of a number. We've had a [similar but more complicated challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11080/give-the-smallest-number-that-has-n-divisors) before, but I'm intending this one to be entry-level.

## The Challenge

Create a program or function that, given one strictly positive integer `N`, outputs or returns how many divisors it has, including 1 and `N`.

Input: One integer > 0. You may assume that the number can be represented in your language's native numeric type.

Output: The number of positive integer divisors it has, including 1 and the number itself.

Submissions will be scored in **bytes**. You may find [this website](http://bytesizematters.com) handy, though you may use any reasonable method for generating your byte count.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest score wins!

**Edit:** It looks like FryAmTheEggman's 5-byte Pyth answer is the winner! Feel free to submit new answers, though; if you can get something shorter, I'll change the accepted answer.

## Test Cases

```
ndiv(1) -> 1
ndiv(2) -> 2
ndiv(12) -> 6
ndiv(30) -> 8
ndiv(60) -> 12
ndiv(97) -> 2
ndiv(100) -> 9
```

## Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=64944,OVERRIDE_USER=45162;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?([\d.]+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Pyth, 5

```
l{yPQ
```

Uses the subsets operation on the prime factors of the input, then keeps only the unique lists of factors and returns this count.

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7ByPQ&input=100&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A12%0A30%0A60%0A97%0A100&debug=0)

#### Explanation

Using 25 as an example, so that the subset list isn't very long

```
l{yPQ     ## implicit:  Q = eval(input()) so Q == 25
   PQ     ## Prime factors of Q, giving [5, 5]
  y       ## All subsets, giving [[], [5], [5], [5, 5]]
 {        ## Unique-fiy, giving [[], [5], [5, 5]]
l         ## Length, print implicity
```

Comment: Fascinating. Nice approach

Answer (score 14):

## <s>C++</s> C, <s>43</s> <s>57</s> <s>56</s> <s>46</s> 43 bytes

On Martin Büttner's suggestions :

```
i,c;f(n){for(i=c=n;i;n%i--&&--c);return c;}
```

Comment: Wait, let's count both of them down instead, for 43: `i,c;f(n){for(i=c=n;i;n%i--&&--c);return c;}`

Comment: @MartinBüttner Wow man wow. Seriously! _/\\_

Comment: Beautiful! :~)!

Answer (score 12):

### LabVIEW, 4938 Bytes

Well its obviously not suited for code golf but whatever, so for my first post and the lolz here goes. [image]

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! How did you score this, if you don't mind me asking? I couldn't find any precedent on Meta.

Comment: i saved it and took the size of it

Comment: And it was 4.938 bytes? Not kilobytes, for instance?

Comment: for accuracy i took the byte count not the kb count

Comment: @bkul I think the confusion is due to the `.`, which I'm pretty sure is meant as a thousand separator, not a decimal point (as is common in some languages).

Comment: @MartinBüttner Ah, thank you. I was confused because the Snippet was parsing it as a decimal.

Comment: By the way there was a discussion in Meta about how to score LabVIEW, http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7502/programming-in-labview-how-to-measure-program-size?cb=1

Comment: I am well aware, if you read the answer there you will find that it´s mine and a proposed way to count^^

Answer (score 11):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

```hs
f n=sum[0^mod n i|i<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxDoAgEATAr2xhC0FreQnBhKDoRTiJaOfbPeO0s4W2LzmLJLBtd3FmKscMBj00Ktdrzd5LCcSwqCfxhQ4lVCT8ORgvb0w5rE1UrPUD)

The trick here is to test whether a remainder is `0` using the indicator function `0^`.

```hs
0^0 = 1
0^_ = 0
```

This works because any positive power of 0 is 0, whereas 0^0 is combinatorially the empty product of 1.

Compare this to filtering

```hs
f n=sum[1|i<-[1..n],mod n i<1]
```

---

**28 bytes**

```hs
f n=sum[1|0<-mod n<$>[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxDoAgDADAr3RghYCz@BHCQFCUSGsjuvl2a7z1ttT3pTWRAuT7jcE9dtR4zECjmoIzhmIUTJXAA5@VLlCAiaHAn4ON8ubS0tpFZ@YP)

An alternative method using matching on a constant. The `<$>` infix `map` might postdate this challenge.

Answer (score 8):

### Python 2, 37 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:i/n or(n%i<1)+f(n,i+1)
```

A recursive function. The optional input `i` in the divisor being tested. The expression `(n%i<1)` tests divisibility, with `True` (which equals `1`) for divisors. The result is added to the recusive expression for `i+1`. When `i==n` is reached, the integer floor-division `i/n` evaluates to `1`, and that value is returned as the base case, accounting for `n` itself being a divisor of `n`.

---

**38:**

```python
lambda n:sum(n%-~i<1for i in range(n))
```

An anonymous function. Tests all possible divisors `1` through `n`. This is shifted up from `0` through `n-1` in `range(n)` using `-~`, which adds `1`. Summing the bools uses the fact that Python treats `True`/`False` as `1`/`0`.

Answer (score 8):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```
≢∘∪⊢∨⍳
```

It is an unnamed function that can be named and then reused for each (`¨`) test case as follows:

```
      f ← ≢∘∪⊢∨⍳
      f¨ 1 2 12 30 60 97 100
1 2 6 8 12 2 9
```

Explanation:

```
 ┌─┴──┐  
 ∪  ┌─┼─┐
 ∘  │ ∨ │
 ̸≡  ⊢   ⍳
```

Count `≢` the `∘` unique `∪` of the GCD `∨` of itself `⊢` and each of the integers-until `⍳`.

Thanks to ngn for saving a byte.

---

Old version: `+/0=⍳|⊢`

This is how it works:

```
  ┌─┴─┐      
  / ┌─┼───┐  
┌─┘ 0 = ┌─┼─┐
+       ⍳ | ⊢
```

`⍳|⊢` 1-through-argument division-remainder argument
`0=` Boolean if 0 is equal to the division rest
`+/` Sum of the boolean, i.e. count of ones.

Answer (score 6):

## Golfscript, <s>19</s> <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 13 bytes

With thanks to [Martin Büttner](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/112128).

```
~.,\{\)%!}+,,
```

#### How it works

```
~               Evaluate the input, n
 .,             Duplicate the input, create array [0..n-1]
   \            Swap array and n
    {    }+     Add n to block == {n block}
     \          Swap n with i in array
      )         Increment i
       %        n mod i
        !       Logical not so that 1 if divisible by n else 0
           ,    Filter array using block for all i divisible by n
            ,   Get length of the filtered array, the answer
```

#### Also

From [@Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor), also in 13 bytes.

```
~:X,{)X\%!},,
```

#### How it works

```
~               Evaluate the input
 :X             Store input in variable X
   ,            Create array [0..X-1]
    {     },    Filter array using the following block
     )          Increment i in array
      X\        Add X to stack, swap with i
        %       X mod i,
         !      Logical not so that 1 if divisible by n else 0
            ,   Get length of the filtered array, the answer
```

Comment: For the same length you could also have `~:X,{)X\%!},,`

Answer (score 6):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 17 bytes

```
(?<=(.+))(?=\1*$)
```

[Input in unary](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary), output in decimal.

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=KD88PSguKykpKD89XDEqJCk&input=MTExMTExMTExMTEx)

When invoked with a single regex, Retina simply counts the matches. The regex itself matches a *position*, where the unary number to the left of it is a divisor of the entire input. I'm also making use of the fact that lookarounds are atomic, so that I don't need to use a `^` anchor.

The first lookbehinds simply captures the entire prefix in group `1`. This can never fail, so after the lookbehind we know that's what's in group 1 and it won't change any more.

The lookahead then checks if we can reach the end of the string by repeating the captured string (our potential divisor) 0 or more times.

Answer (score 6):

## J, 10 bytes

```
[:*/1+_&q:
```

This is an unnamed, monadic verb. It calculates **σ<sub>0</sub>(∏p<sub>k</sub><sup>α<sub>k</sub></sup>)** as **∏(α<sub>k</sub> + 1)**.

Try it online with [J.js](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=(%20%5B%3A*%2F1%2B_%26q%3A%20)%20each%201%202%2012%2030%2060%2097%20100).

#### How it works

```
[:*/1+_&q:    Right argument: y

      _&q:    Compute all exponents of the prime factorization of y.
    1+        Add 1 to each exponent.
[:*/          Reduce by mutiplication.
```

Comment: I don't think `q:` is allowed as it solves an essential part of the challenge. How about just `[:+/0=]|~1+i.`

Comment: That would be a duplicate of [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64974). Also, built-ins are not forbidden by default, and the challenge doesn't seem to mention them.

Comment: Builtins that do all / almost all of the work of a challenge are usually forbidden but I can follow your reasoning for `q: `.

Comment: [They are not.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1078) I wish they were, but they are not.

Comment: Hrmpf hrmpf that sucks a little.

Answer (score 4):

## J, <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

My first golf in J. I'm still learning it.

Saved a byte thanks to Dennis.

Saved one more byte thanks to randomra.

```
1+/@,0=i.|]
```

Explanation:

```
1+/@,0=i.|]
       i.        the array 0 .. n-1
         |]      mod n
     0=          replace 0 by 1, and nonzero entries by 0
1   ,            prepend 1 to the array
 +/@             take the sum
```

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 20 bytes

```julia
n->sum(i->n%i<1,1:n)
```

This is an anonymous function that works as follows: For each integer from 1 to the input, test whether the input modulo the integer is zero. If so, the value will be `true`, otherwise `false`. We sum over the booleans which are implicitly cast to integers, yielding the number of divisors.

---

A much cooler (though also much longer) solution, included for the sake of completeness, is

```julia
n->prod(collect(values(factor(n))).+1)
```

This gets the canonical factorization of `n`, i.e. `\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^e_i`, and computes the divisor function as `τ(n) = \prod_{i=1}^k e_i + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Arcyóu](https://github.com/nazek42/arcyou), 12 bytes

Let's get the party started!

```
(F(x)(_(d/ x
```

This uses the built-in function `d/`. Here's a version without the built-in (27 bytes):

```
(F(x)(](+(f i(_ 1 x)(‰ x i
```

Explanation:

```
(F(x)              ; Anonymous function with one parameter x
  (]               ; Increment
    (+             ; Sum
      (f i(_ 1 x)  ; For i in range from 1 to x-1 inclusive:
        (‰ x i     ; x divisible by i
```

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 11 bytes

```
ri_,:)f%0e=
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~_%2C%3A)f%250e%3D&input=12)

#### Explanation

CJam doesn't have a built-in for this, so we're doing trial division.

```
ri  e# Read input and convert to integer N.
_,  e# Duplicate and turn into range [0 1 ... N-1]
:)  e# Increment each element in the range to get [1 2 ... N]
f%  e# Take N modulo each of the list elements.
0e= e# Count the zeroes.
```

#### Bonus

Here is an interesting solution at 12 bytes (which I suspect might be shortest in a language like J):

```
ri_)2m*::*e=
```

The result is equal to the number of times `n` appears in an `n x n` multiplication table:

```
ri  e# Read input and convert to integer N.
_)  e# Duplicate and increment.
2m* e# Take Cartesian product of [0 1 ... N] with itself.
::* e# Compute the product of each pair.
e=  e# Count the occurrences of N.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab, 20 bytes

Perform `k mod n` for every `k = 1,...,n`, then perform `not` (which turns every nonzer to zero and every zero to 1) and sum up all those values.

```
@(n)sum(~mod(n,1:n))
```

Comment: This would have been my approach too!

Comment: Interesting that this is the same length as `length(divisors(n))`.

Comment: @Acccumulation you'd still need to add a `@(n)` to make it a valid submisison

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Æd
```

[Try it online!](//jelly.tryitonline.net#code=w4Zk&args=NjA)

I *think* this uses features implemented after the other Jelly answer. Comment if I'm wrong though (I can't look each commit in the row, you know :))

Answer (score 3):

## Excel Formula, <s>42</s> 28 bytes

Edit: I just realised I do not need to use `INDIRECT`, saving 14 bytes!

The following should be entered as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=SUM(--NOT(MOD(N,ROW(1:N))))
```

Where N is the number to test.

**Examples:**

```
{SUM(--NOT(MOD(32,ROW(1:32))))}
Result: 6
{SUM(--NOT(MOD(144,ROW(1:144))))}
Result: 15
```

**Explanation:**

```
SUM(--NOT(MOD(N,ROW(1:N))))       Full formula

                ROW(1:N)          Generates an array of row numbers e.g {1;2;3;4;...N}
          MOD(N,ROW(1:N))         Does N MOD {1;2;3;4;,...N}
      NOT(MOD(N,ROW(1:N)))        Coerces zeros to ones, so that they may be counted, but actually returns an array of TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;...
    --NOT(MOD(N,ROW(1:N)))        Coerces the TRUEs to 1s and FALSEs to 0s.
SUM(--NOT(MOD(N,ROW(1:N))))       Sum the ones for the result.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ñg
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MT0//8NDQwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/wxPT/@v8jzbUMdIxNNIxNtAxM9CxNNcxNDCIBQA).

**Explanation:**

Pretty straight-forward, but here it is anyway:

```python
Ñ   # Push a list of divisors of the (implicit) input-integer
    #  i.e. 100 → [1,2,4,5,10,20,25,50,100]
 g  # Pop and push the length of this list
    #  i.e. [1,2,4,5,10,20,25,50,100] → 9
    # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

Simple trial division.

```
lf!%QTSQ
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lf%21%25QTSQ&input=12&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A12%0A30%0A60%0A97%0A100&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## PARI/GP, 6 bytes

PARI/GP have a built-in for this.

```
numdiv
```

Comment: i'm not sure, but I think that according to meta, for builtins, you can't merely restate it.

Comment: @Maltysen I think it's allowed. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7206/9288

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
@(n)nnz(~mod(n,1:n))
```

Comment: I like the `nnz`, great usage here=)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 27 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1..n).count{|i|n%i<1}}
```

Sample run:

```
2.1.5 :001 > ->n{(1..n).count{|i|n%i<1}}[100]
 => 9
```

Answer (score 2):

## Regex (.NET), 33 bytes

```
^((?=.*$(?<=^\2*(.+?(?>\2?)))).)+
```

Assuming input and output are in unary, and the output is taken from the main match of the regex.

Break down of the regex:

- `.*$` ets the pointer to the end of the string so that we have the whole input x in one direction.
- `(?<=^\2*(.+?(?>\2?)))` matches from right to left and checks for divisor by looping from x to 0.

  - `(.+?(?>\2?))` is a "variable" which starts from 1 in the first iteration and continues from the number in previous iteration and loops up to x.
  - `^\2*` checks whether x is a multiple of "variable".

It basically has the same idea as my answer to [Calculate Phi (not Pi)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63710/calculate-phi-not-pi/63738#63738). Only the check is different.

Test the regex at [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester).

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>60</s> <s>57</s> <s>42</s> <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 37 bytes

This can probably be golfed better.

```
n=>{for(d=i=n;i;n%i--&&d--);return d}
```

**Edit 1:** I was right. Removed the braces after the for loop.

**Edit 2:** Golfed to 40 bytes with thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) and [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner).

**Edit 3:** Saving a byte by basing the function on [the C answer above.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64978/47581)

**Edit 4:** Thanks to [ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41247/%D7%9Fn%C9%9Fu%C9%90%C9%AF%C9%B9%C9%90%D7%9Fo%C9%AF) and [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil), but I can't get the eval to work.

**Edit 5:** Forgot to remove the eval.

#### Test

```html
n = <input type="number" oninput='result.innerHTML=(

n=>{for(d=i=n;i;n%i--&&d--);return d}

)(+this.value)' /><pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Give up the good habits. Remove `var` keywords. More tips in [Tips for golfing in JavaScript](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) and [Tips for Golfing in ECMAScript 6](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37624/tips-for-golfing-in-ecmascript-6).

Comment: Also give up the bad habits: when you've got a choice between `++i` and `i++`, choose the former (this has nothing to do with golfing). Also `n%i<1` should save a byte.

Comment: Only briefly tested: `n=>{for(d=i=0;i<n;)n%++i<1&&d++;return d}`

Comment: 38: n=>eval('for(d=0,i=n;i;d+=n%i--<1);d')

Comment: @manatwork Why not `n%++i||++d`?

Comment: Using @MartinBüttner's C suggestion saves another 2 bytes: `n=>{for(d=i=n;i;n%i--&&d--);return d}`

Comment: @Neil, I was distracted by other tasks when I wrote it. Realized the clumsiness just later when I saw [Sahil Arora](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47647/sahil-arora)'s [C solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64978).

Comment: Use eval to save bytes

Answer (score 2):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 33 bytes

```
?:}
  :{:}%{{
@ }   " )
!{("{;"}}
```

[Try it online.](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=Pzp9CiAgOns6fSV7ewpAIH0gICAiICkKIXsoIns7In19&input=MTI)

This implements trial division. I'll add a full explanation later. It's probably not optimal, but I'm having a hard time coming up with something shorter.

Answer (score 2):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 17 bytes

```perl6
{[+] $_ X%%1..$_} # 17
```

usage:

```perl6
say {[+] $_ X%%1..$_}(60); # 12␤

my $code = {[+] $_ X%%1..$_};

say $code(97); # 2␤

my &code = $code;
say code 92; # 6
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ÆDL
```

Uses the builtin for divisors.

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 34 bytes

```
param($x)(1..$x|?{!($x%$_)}).Count

e.g. 

PS C:\temp> .\divisors-of-x.ps1 97
2
```

- create a list of numbers from 1 to x, feed them into the pipeline `|`
- filter the pipeline on (x % item == 0), by implicitly casting the modulo result as a boolean and then inverting it using `!` so divisors become $true and are allowed through; using the builtin alias `?` for `Where-Object`
- gather up `()` and `.Count` how many items got through the filter

Comment: Very nicely hacked!

Answer (score 2):

## Taxi, 2143 bytes

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 1 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 r.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Firemouth Grill.Pickup a passenger going to Joyless Park.Go to Firemouth Grill:s 1 l 2 l 1 r.Go to Joyless Park:e 1 l 3 r.[i][Check next value n-i]Go to Zoom Zoom:w 1 r 2 l 2 r.Go to Sunny Skies Park:w 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.Go to Joyless Park:n 2 r 2 r 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Sunny Skies Park:w 1 r 2 l 2 l 1 l.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Joyless Park.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.Go to Divide and Conquer:n 2 r 2 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:e 1 l 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Trunkers:s 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Equal's Corner:w 1 l.Switch to plan "F" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Knots Landing.Go to Firemouth Grill:n 3 r 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to The Underground:e 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Firemouth Grill.Go to Knots Landing:n 2 r.Go to Firemouth Grill:w 1 l 2 r.Go to Joyless Park:e 1 l 3 r.Switch to plan "N".[F][Value not a divisor]Go to Joyless Park:n 3 r 1 r 2 l 4 r.[N]Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to The Underground:w 1 l.Switch to plan "E" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Joyless Park.Go to Joyless Park:n 1 r.Switch to plan "i".[E]Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 3 l 2 l 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to What's The Difference.Go to Firemouth Grill:s 1 l 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to What's The Difference.Go to What's The Difference:w 1 l 1 r 2 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:e 3 r.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 l 1 r.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/taxi#rVZNj5swEP0ro1x6Ktpke8qx2WSlttpGSj@kRhxcGIKFd5y1zdL8@tTGbAqEdUPaAyDsmeeZNzMPjvcSjIS11AY@ZxlPcF7BFIS9lHtGa54U5R4Y7JnWSDtUsJOcds7rS47wnv1EkXGdozpEHqy/PNcviEG0xSERkrABad7m1PgKmF3oH7LZlEQH2BQcNayZKprD@sv1qWookiD6iit8lKXJ4V5xEbb9IA8CdSeKnntD26yhztu03eZYG9zazS2Pt4sckwIIfxl4ZqJEoLc89l4/pHysb3VxVY05O2GeZV85g2trFfS74888RWCUwkLSU4nqmnJ1SCCXSXONCXog6z/U1B03OrtOTUfS4M8632jld90AYWuA/jLOqqQClQ4aLZ9KJt5oG56iU9gvnr5lx/t3F70CRZuKmyR323vBCCarCfAMSILNCriGinFjQYOnfSRpNHyyfDrL4TEjN0EXKZQTtq@UotopWVLakrvWqid8lE54nE6svuyvRFyd9DAoCn0CHybRdhVvv3lxkMYGl9p@01LFg3PlafEj8c6JzEP87@wM13Z5RW0HFLSXwHSABG5JWMavyv5ta/xDh3/PmbEN67K741mGCinBoI5f0mAh1MG91sd69h8/2Fj3Twip9cMQnf9C0Cnb43F6c/Mb)

Ungolfed:

```
Go to Post Office: west 1st left 1st right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: south 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: north 1st left 1st left 2nd right.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Go to Sunny Skies Park: north 1st right.
Go to Cyclone: north 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Firemouth Grill.
Pickup a passenger going to Joyless Park.
Go to Firemouth Grill: south 1st left 2nd left 1st right.
Go to Joyless Park: east 1st left 3rd right.
[i]
[Check next value n-i]
Go to Zoom Zoom: west 1st right 2nd left 2nd right.
Go to Sunny Skies Park: west 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: north 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Go to Joyless Park: north 2nd right 2nd right 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Sunny Skies Park: west 1st right 2nd left 2nd left 1st left.
Go to Cyclone: north 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Joyless Park.
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.
Go to Divide and Conquer: north 2nd right 2nd right 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: east 1st left 1st left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Go to Trunkers: south 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Go to Equal's Corner: west 1st left.
Switch to plan "F" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Knots Landing.
Go to Firemouth Grill: north 3rd right 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.
Go to The Underground: east 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Firemouth Grill.
Go to Knots Landing: north 2nd right.
Go to Firemouth Grill: west 1st left 2nd right.
Go to Joyless Park: east 1st left 3rd right.
Switch to plan "N".
[F]
[Value not a divisor]
Go to Joyless Park: north 3rd right 1st right 2nd left 4th right.
[N]
Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.
Go to The Underground: west 1st left.
Switch to plan "E" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Joyless Park.
Go to Joyless Park: north 1st right.
Switch to plan "i".
[E]
Go to Sunny Skies Park: north 3rd left 2nd left 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to What's The Difference.
Go to Firemouth Grill: south 1st left 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to What's The Difference.
Go to What's The Difference: west 1st left 1st right 2nd right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: east 3rd right.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: north 1st left 1st right.
```

Explanation:

```
Convert stdin to a number and store it in three locations for three purposes:
   Original (Sunny Skies Park)
   Counter for tested values (Joyless Park)
   Counter for divisors found (Firemouth Grill)
Divide the original by each Joyless Park value in turn.
If the division result equals the truncated division result, then it's a divisor.
When a divisor is found, subtract one from Firemouth Grill.
Repeat until Joyless Park hits zero.
Pickup the original from Sunny Skies Park and subtract the value from Firemouth Grill.
Convert the result to a string and print to stdout.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

```
â l
```

`-m` flag is for running all the test cases.

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=4iBs&input=WzEsCjIsCjEyLAozMCwKNjAsCjk3LAoxMDBd)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 14 bytes

```
sum(not(fPart(Ans/cumSum(binomcdf(Ans-1,0
```

Input is in `Ans`.
Output is in `Ans` and is implicitly printed.

This submission will only work for \$1<N<1000\$ due to limitations in the TI calculators.

**Examples:**

```
25
              25
prgmCDGF14
               3
100
             100
prgmCDGF14
               9
```

**Explanation:**

```
sum(not(fPart(Ans/cumSum(binomcdf(Ans-1,0   ;full program

                         binomcdf(Ans-1,0   ;generate a list of 1s whose length is the input
                  cumSum(                   ;calculate the cumulative sum
              Ans/                          ;divide the input by each term
        fPart(                              ;get the fractional part of each element
    not(                                    ;logically negate each term
                                            ; 0 becomes 1
                                            ; everything else becomes 0
sum(                                        ;sum the list
                                            ;implicit print of "Ans"
```

---

If the above submission does not suffice, then the following **24 byte** submission also works for \$0<N<10^{100}\$

```
Ans→N:0:For(I,1,N:Ans+not(fPart(N/I:End:Ans
```

**Examples:**

```
25
              25
prgmCDGF14
               3
100
             100
prgmCDGF14
               9
```

**Explanation:**

```
Ans→N:0:For(I,1,N:Ans+not(fPart(N/I:End:Ans   ;full program

Ans→N                                         ;store the input in "N"
      0                                       ;leave 0 in "Ans"
        For(I,1,N                   End       ;loop over all integers in [1,N]
                  Ans+not(fPart(N/I           ;increment "Ans" if the current "I"
                                              ; is a factor of "N"
                                        Ans   ;leave "Ans" as the last expression
                                              ;implicit print of "Ans"
```

---

**Note:**  TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does ***not*** equal byte count.

Answer (score 2):

## [krrp](https://github.com/jfrech/krrp), 22 bytes

```
^n:,^k:&k+=%nk0@-k1.n.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy4qKvivGJ2XklkW@z8uz0onLttKLVvbVjUv28BBN9tQL0/vf4xPdG5iQaw1RJWPoY@Rj4qhkZ6PirEBkDADEZbmQMLQwEDP9T8A)

---

## Explanation

```
^n:       ~ an anonymous function of arity one
 ,^k:     ~  apply the following function (*) of arity one
  &k      ~   if `k` is zero, return zero; else
   +      ~    add
    =%nk0 ~     boolean (if `k` is a divisor of `n`)
    @-k1. ~     to the current function (*) itself applied to `k-1`
 n.       ~  to `n`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBdSwMxEHzvrxihSqvtcVdBsUXwxbf7B7UlsZdoSLp7JDnlfPCvn/dRe@iyDGSYyc6u9b5sLrZUmI9ds6c1hvqGpLaZ6iNXAbqiQzRMYA3pTazBpCZY7O36JIcsS1cjvitodo4/Db2Nttn1/J8VV/Z3EmA0hBUwAV/K8wJexcpT/9hAudDpcTPqIYuio/B4STYdKLwyO9Wmno2/SbRrmcC@Gy5IzHvT09JmyckUuY98qLxXFP8GNjEop/vFjCo6qbDLTExAyflKPUuiecm3R1nuNsMh8yxf5dNsleTT27SFuw4e7lvI0jR5bn4A)

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 3 bytes

```
Lz$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/36dK5f9/QyMA)

### Explanation

```
:Lz$
:       (implicit) given input n, output nth term in sequence
          each term in sequence equals:
 L                                      length (                    )
  z                                              divisors (       )
   $                                                        index
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
fl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qGXqo6bGR51zHrVtADG6lnKVKyno2ikolduDhZoUH@7qfNTU8D8t5/9/AA)

Takes input through its input variable and outputs through its output variable.

```
f     The list of factors of
      the input variable
 l    has length equal to
      the output variable.
```

[This exact same predicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184722/85334), taking input through its output variable and outputting through its input variable, [solves this challenge instead](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11080/85334).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>32</s>30 bytes

```
n=(x,y=x)=>y?n(x,y-1)+!(x%y):1
```

Ungolf:

```
n=(x,y=x)=>                     //function declaration with y=x preset
           y?                   //check if y=0
             n(x,y+1)           //next divisor(current-1)
                     +!(x%y)    //1 if y is a divisor of x, 0 if not. Or, if x mod y=0.
                            :0  //if y=1, then 0(base case)
```

32B->30B, -2B for reversing the loop, reducing the condition `x-y` to `y`.

Answer (score 2):

## x86-16 machine code, 15 bytes

```
 8B C8          MOV  CX, AX                 ; store input as counter
            DEC_LOOP: 
 50             PUSH AX                     ; save input number
 88 0E 0108     MOV  BYTE PTR[AAM1+1], CL   ; modify AAM code operand's second byte
            AAM1: 
 D4 0A          AAM                         ; ZF = ( AL % CL == 0 )
 75 01          JNZ  END_LOOP               ; if remainder not 0, continue loop
 43             INC  BX                     ; otherwise increment BX
            END_LOOP: 
 58             POP  AX                     ; restore input number
 E2 F3          LOOP DEC_LOOP
```

Input is `AX`, output is `BX`.

This uses (abuses) the arbitrary base ability of the `AAM` instruction to check if each factor is divisible.  It self-modifies the second byte of the opcode of the `AAM` with the divisor on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 30 bytes

```
\sum_{n=1}^m(1-sign(mod(m,n)))
```

Alternatively:

```
m-sign(mod(m,[1,...,m])).total
```

[View them online](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i1dtgqugga)

Comment: You can save a few bytes in your first answer by replacing `1-sign(...)` with `0^{...}`: `\sum_{n=1}^m0^{mod(m,n)}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 3 bytes

```
:d%
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3Ad%25&i=1%0A2%0A12%0A30%0A60%0A97%0A100&m=2)

It's the same size when packed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 6 bytes

```
rifcL[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/KDMt2Sf6/39DAwMA)

Explanation:

```
ri     # Read integer from input string
  fc   # Get list of factors
    L[ # Get length and implicitly output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 1 byte

```
   # Count Divisors
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCXP@/zcyBQA)

I posted this on a duplicate which got closed, so I figured I'd post it here.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 90 bytes

```
listen to N
X's0
D's0
while N-X
let X be+1
let M be N/X
turn up M
let D be+M is N/X

say D
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 2):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), <s>32</s> 29 bytes

```
+?
Fx,`r,x%i,=0,Ir,,`y,,+1
Oy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/7/Cyp7LrUInoUinQjVTp8jWQMezSEcnoVJHp1LbkMu/8v///4YGBgA)

### Explained (old)

```
x:?             # Set x to the input
Fx,             # For i in range(x):
    `r,         #       Set the active variable r AND
    x%i,        #       Assign to it the result of x%i
    r=0,        #       And then the result of r==0
    Ir,,        #       If r == 1:
        `y,,    #           Set the active variable to y AND
        y+1     #           Assign to it y + 1
Oy              # Output variable y
```

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/1/bnsutQiehSKdCNVPH1kDHs0hHJ6FSR0fbkMu/8v///4YGBg). Taking advantage of the fact you can omit variables when they’re active, and `+?` works for taking integer input rather than `x:?`

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 16 bytes

```
Length@*Divisors
```

Simple function composition of built-ins.

Answer (score 1):

### [Minkolang 0.13](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 16 bytes

```
ndd[0ci1+%,-]-N.
```

[Check all cases here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%28ndd%5B0ci1%2B%25%2C-%5D-n%3DNlO%24I%29%2E&input=1%201%0A2%202%0A12%206%0A30%208%0A60%2012%0A97%202%0A100%209)

#### Explanation

```
ndd           Takes number from input and duplicates it twice (n)
[             Opens for loop that runs n times
 0c           Copies bottom of stack to top (n)
   i1+        Loop counter + 1 (d)
      %       Modulo - pops d,n, then pushes n%d
       ,      Not - 1 if equal to 0, 0 otherwise
        -     Subtract
         ]    Close for loop
-             Subtract (n - 1 for each non-divisor)
N.            Output as number and stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 17 bytes

```
,;n;;╟@RZ`i@%Y`MΣ
```

[Try it online with explanation](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=2c3b6e3b3bc740525a6069402559604de4&input=100)

If my prime factorization function had been working before this challenge, I could get [9 bytes](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/eyJjb2RlIjoiLHdgaVh1YE3PgCIsImlucHV0IjoiMTgifQ%3D%3D):

```
,w`iXu`Mπ
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 61 bytes

```
<?$x=$_GET['x'];for($i=1;$i<=$x;$i++)$c+=$x%$i==0?1:0;echo$c;
```

I don't know if there's a shorter way to get input in PHP, so I use `$_GET`.

Comment: There´s no shorter input, only `$argv[1]` which has the same length; but [here](http://ideone.com/msRKII) are some tips to golf this down to 42 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## O, 21 bytes

```
0[Q{Qn)%}d]{n{}{)}?}d
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ./o o.o <<< 100
9
```

Comment: This is a placeholder until @phase posts the proper O solution.

Answer (score 1):

### TI-BASIC, 10 bytes

```
sum(not(fPart(Ans/randIntNoRep(1,Ans
```

This won't work for numbers >999, since that's the maximum size of a list.

Comment: I'm honestly somewhat surprised that TI-BASIC doesn't have a builtin for divisors.

Comment: [This looks familiar...](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57870/29750)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 29 bytes

```js
f=(n,i=n)=>i&&f(n,i-1)+!(n%i)
```

Recursive solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src/5ebf758a930fa4f4140d49db53b3ce8359aa1b65?at=master) (noncompeting), 4 bytes

Hex:

```
1A 3A 47 27
```

Explanation:

```
1A - Input from STDIN
3A - List of factors
47 - Length
27 - Output (with newline)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 41 bytes

```forth
: f 0 over 1+ 1 do over i mod 0= - loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvBCoMwEETvfsXDa0lIKiit6M8Yo4JlQ2j9/bihh3k7M@xEyd/dbLGeUt5EHHKtGf/AE@QfDj4ScBOGUyQx6mci/BIdNmNbMDOtri1LZmw8qXmqfEXnFH3Fa6idU1tu)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f            \ start a new word definition
  0 over 1+ 1  \ set up loop parameters and a value to store the count in
  do           \ loop from 1 to n
    over       \ get n and put it on top of the stack
    i mod 0=   \ check if the current loop index is a divisor of n
    -          \ if so, subtract it from the counter (-1 = true in forth)
  loop         \ end the loop
;              \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

### [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 42 bytes

```
n=>Enumerable.Range(1,n).Count(x=>n%x==0);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXogPEdgppCrb/82ztXPNKc1OLEpNyUvWCEvPSUzUMdfI09ZzzS/NKNCps7fJUK2xtDTSt/4cXZZak@mTmpWqkaRhqalpzoQgYoYsYG6CLmGGIWJpjmGMAUvQfAA)

Comment: Suggest `n%x<1` instead of `n%x==0`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 21 bytes

```perl
$_-=grep"@F"%$_,1..$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXtc2vSi1QMnBTUlVJV7HUE9PJf7/f9N/@QUlmfl5xf91CxIB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 31 bytes

```c
O;=x+=z=y 0P;W>x y=z+z!%x=y+yTz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVlbU9tKEn62f8XgFJZGlhNZsFWnbGSK5JAUtQRyINk8gDcIWcaqlWWvJHMN@9ez3T0XjWyT3eweHizP6Oue7m96untM1L2Joh@vkixKl@N4ryjHyfz1dNg0Z9LkujYVlQ@LeAWUJ9lNbapMZgIzjidJFrM0Zek8u6GPpp79fPLlI@tVw/PPZ8yvhn87OGO71fD9yTv2WzU8@8J6Ffj98bmBPflybEC/nHw8OP@rXXBm40eb/av3F67fHpzDsuLlMiuSmywes2ga5szhlaQJB6O1ruGQ7VbvTg6/4ssMXpJr3xl@39tbweB6hEF/AZOmHIE1zNvT02MC4cc@edtHJw1Dzj4IAMgbtt6G6TLm/CIb8WaT/IDtuRgF7Kx1eHpu/zgdBPed4DF4YN6nwdfhPXsIHjuPW9v3wUPn4fPjDw6o1kBIOiAahzMWoI5BswkLLcK8iG3OnpqNJCtZMmg2YJYWdZkzWWYRzJBwBONytnCLRXbhj4Inz/WeQUcjAXWEh6eHE2/eoPpkwe6mSRkXizCKmw34nsY2zIO4LcxwWeuyvMwuJ5c5e3q@GNm8/6rFyZRGMmG2tjZg1iuLM6FCzW7B7GUG052OmAE7G3FaxObEszAnmsbRP9hknrNsObuO80Law@ykGCc3Sam0wuroTs/VHomnw3oe6zBHWt7pcNZllmfBEmhpwlkel8s8YypMhBhFymDVhtswT8LrNFZWgBHp/C7O7QjWU4aw79@ZMi6iUUREfLO4pCfZ4HoS9FzYo0BPr1iHJ1AGKECy8XJh45YyyWmXwWjdYJEPCqFNmHFpWZVNLUtsGgiDB9ooBkogf8B3sGwRFiUrpzEoC/MSwHIDHMUobmjE0RNlrHGaXjQWPnucNrpRkUHmY@iWyTwDszFivRGYFilGiuVigYRzFVVqxqTfjD@g3SAbdahQXmQQx5DLMHKl5YKVz5Y@52LiPU5gXutjPkMzVZBRKhSu2mg3mhqm6Tyydz23x9FBnNZOkIPZMk3D/MF0tNqfM2N7PlnaMlpQyi@zFWlaoodLyKSwydODw7fvrv7YOv791HDYVHudbNTrr@vdqin@cHT@gsYyzkllmI3ZP5ehGqLaW3OJnfUlBAEfLM3F0QYuSHi3LlzHPFOqzJcZ7tBApmGnnBe2ypV0ACC0yyQSxeZ6Obnwd0fSDrHRbUoP2oBiAceqnNgABf@303TcUnmHypCLSlYVwKHQCkSlE@vXcHust1P3E53HWNxnrTJfxi2IQT2PIQnzkxAyCL5oYWS1KhLQT/RdViKi49vb@TyFN9d1Bl70tXLrZw45v@6Raeb1mpkp2pj9qTZC0JbzNLVNU13muVAh/geTszWTsQp/PPh04mItFoEGw6OLnud5EE7gCgzVqEge428lw8fAiFHDW2QARi5@@PS5E/RUSccMh1UdH/Tpi8cOAN4fHR86bALJcdDQoS3XwzQchQs3jTPqAAyuVKMkOINz9xIZq4JYm7C0YcGxE@oloBbvERcDKCoJvtR5I5otVnaASEpGVQpBmpIRLlPcJWU0tR1gZq2vAo6Y/IuwTlkHVp/hKgIQIKHYmUEW5m1ySqqXvWEtZPmAqnCFoE60zLF02cj4xYg/VWEGDRTldrHwGSxc151DxrN527uf4F@F/ARI0Co4uonLFNpHu0172cYdwhI5TjI@SCa2TfuJDUE0zdEWF@KUc7HNgTfYaCs8OLUBYr1DsZ7oHDEbSEIGyl4kSebOysq3lT8Cr9@8q96gpEmxxlwBBqMB4i9YzBdxZhsLu628Ra0CWBXMRKWEeAx8b/c3mpfNhS06kgmYPkanoIWDkHWxvwM49A40wjVgaRVeNkyyTkCtEJ5YQHJJN@ihtYhq1OAEzDd7lorGypM/wJP4Hto4PO1rfm7Vdp1uCVuYydaAx2vhAaukdV4M@O9WX/aJGwJZZz5ZgVon1BbbWIO4KkLD4S6vGsu1dKhEz6k5tLcLFKwfhnVhoBNaH3NdyKS8VUHVCywvcZhJtS@VMFmzzB2QuUWycFqxgAdDXHyQNLGfNepYu01Xq24XoSPR5l5Su91QZm2/dgqwx4YRZ@qo5Yb5y7JQu69jQvR6wqCONojyJORLTMkYWsb2iG66Ud9tcU9FNPT9TMWSL/Yc@186DGIDCIXTeMoD5aXPN4dqFJbqIbvOXqeiiavvqItDN@rSs5Q5QvrVXYtOI9qxVa/bK4Scanc2sLBanjfw4KzxIPZ1EwuzDa45hAlMJSQANcimDBlYl3DJQ9Cg2yV9kigqmasbLRgta6f/zU@JebOZmO2fCm1vFvo7sVlzSFwdaM43vRxI2gXrAev2NMuEBep7cM66PThjPRPs/yJ6D9JjDRsECKV1@2rGU5QT0f7Qk1z7nNoVJyD@m6sHgl6SK3BHoASLJQa@45VhGuexVbBsDj10kpZJxu7CB@CNjedwJy3jmzgHmcU8i7MyCfEWASd5zu5iNg1vYwBKRQgv2SzMlhA@D69xFr27RsaBCmKiWKYl/mhAi@uEpyBdE6OWXKHMlNOQFfWo72Wk97IhGrZXQ3l0Pw9TrI0P4HU2TuMxu6rMvtJanvCbaMyMRSpnhqis21VjTvCGhDqG6c86D@5RsK4UPkx6tbwY1LPiPjMP/555DFC0L3@BazMB2Ge1RpEmXWZkQ9ThCUlVcn1RBxC7FUC1MbqgIRxKDK35eN5ns3gWLTDMMja82v9/XRn@Ca4MlStbG3wJpC/Slf2X2RerbjAZX@@zGsDXCF8V0K1NdlYD7Z7KPKYCbV67Sn/oy6basG9KylSi5b//N/IyBxlqtPzA6pvoWpu7ig2qrFt//csXGdXbVjcZxDVqtxmdCgmDGkdBTdpIkyiBiE5HiwmTv4J74lcvs9GsecfM3kWKHdW7doQa8vt@f8eg5YO4MgRGh9UxC9D6HSmTFw9Xn4WdWkN7LoheUTpYLXn@ppK3w3Uf4GvpXZr8Dw0RGoZP3IpIN/@6HTJ7Ix88xFU7PWySqEEQ8S9e0oMQHXkSYPVxPAkhSYJnqsNMMniZiP9YhFEJZcrajizsOXGGsxdusahM10DoBuUPCbMwybBZZWF@E7mk1HHg@y3Hn6vofon/2bE9sqZ@jXv@seP9Gw)

`;` go brrrrr

This is a good example of how ordering and chaining can save bytes in Knight (in a manner similar to recursion).

`;` evaluates two statements and returns **the second result** which is useful when you have case conflicts.

```php
OUTPUT
   # Chain all but the last z
   # x = prompt(), z = y = 0
   ; (=x + (=z=y 0) PROMPT)
   # Loop for each y up to x
   ; WHILE > x y
       # If x % ++y == 0, increment z
       = z + z (! % x (= y + y 1))
   # The actual statement outputted at the end
   : z
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
KL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJLTCIsIiIsIjEyIl0=)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 15 bytes

Number of divisors, using the prime factorization built-in `P`, and to avoid an error with 0 < input < 2, where `P1 == []` and would break the lambda, it returns 1, since there's only one divisor in that case. Special thanks to [@orlp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565635/orlp)

[Try it online here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JrPQ8%3FlJ*FmhhdJ1&input=1%0A2%0A3%0A45%0A5%0A%0A&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A45%0A5&debug=1)

```
JrPQ8?J*FmhhdJ1
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, <s>19</s> 21 bytes

<s>Assume, n is defined as the number</s>

```
sum(mod(n,1:n)==0)
```

If the function style is required

```
function t(n)
sum(mod(n,1:n)==0)
```

Edit: As explained in the comments fixed as an anonymous function and further golfed:

```
@(n)sum(mod(n,1:n)<1)
```

Comment: You can save one byte by doing: `sum(mod(n,1:n)<1)`

Comment: Jonas, you can make it an anonymous function by simply adding an @(n) in front of it. You can then call the function: `ans(12)`. (i.e. you don't need `function`.)

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 34 bytes

```
f={n->(1..n).findAll{n%it<1}.size}
```

Provides function `f` that finds all divisors of `n` and returns the size.

Answer (score 0):

## [Candy](https://github.com/dale6john/candy), 11 bytes

With the value to test already pushed onto the stack:

`~xR(XW%nh)Z`

This translates into long form:

```
peekA   # copy argument from stack into register A
XGetsA  # X := A
range1  # pop argument from stack, push arg, arg - 1, arg - 2, ... 1
while   # while stack not empty
  pushX
  swap    # swap two top stack entries
  mod     # iterated value mod X
  not     # modulo == 0 ?
  popAddZ # Z := Z + popped
endwhile
pushZ     # push Z onto stack, on termination a single value popped and printed
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ceylon, <s>54</s> 47

```
Integer d(Integer n)=>(1..n).count((i)=>n%i<1);
```

This defines a function `d` which is almost straightforward: Take the list of integers from 1 to n (both inclusive), and apply to each the anonymous function `(i) => n%i < 1` (which is a shorter way of writing `(i) => i.divides(n)`), and count how often it returns true.

Formatted it could look like this:

```
Integer d(Integer n) =>
        (1..n).count((i) => n%i < 1);
```

Here we have two versions of 54 bytes each:

`Integer d(Integer c)=>{for(i in 1..n)if(n%i<1)i}.size;`

`Integer d(Integer c)=>sum{1,for(i in 2..n)if(n%i<1)1};`

Both use an Iterable comprehension composed of a `for` and an `if` clause, with one using `.size` and the other one using `sum`, but with an additional literal first entry to convince the compiler it is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 40 bytes

```
filter d($n){(1..$n|?{!($n%$_)}).Count}
```

or

```
filter d($n){1..$n|%{$s+=+!($n%$_)};$s}
```

Both versions have the same length. Can't seem to get it shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 13 bytes

Assuming that the input is stored in the variable named N.

```
sum(N%%1:N==0)
```

Generates a vector of integers from 1 to N, takes N mod each of them, and counts how many of them are 0.

Answer (score 0):

## [O](https://github.com/phase/o), <s>20</s> <s>18</s> 15 bytes

```
[H,;]{Qn%0=}d]+
```

```
[            ]+ Find the sum of
 H,;]            a list of numbers from the input to 1
     {Qn%0=}d    where we find the mod of the input and each number in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 53 Bytes

```
func d(i){c=0 for(n=1;n<=i;n++)i%n==0?c++:""print(c)}
```

See expanded and run online with test case [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=d1b8216023e0c32d2c98df76d5e8e0e8)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 53 bytes

```cs
I=>{int s=0,i=1;for(;i<=I;)if(I%i++<1)s++;return s;};
```

Recursive solution, **72** bytes:

```cs
I=>{return y(I,1);};y=(J,C)=>{return C==J?1:J%C<1?1+y(J,C++):y(J,C++);};
```

Okay, recursion was not the answer here since I needed a helper function.

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom 27 bytes

```
f(x)==(x=1=>1;#divisors(x))
```

results

```
(21) -> for i in [1,2,12,30,60,97,100] repeat output [i,f(i)]
   [1,1]
   [2,2]
   [12,6]
   [30,8]
   [60,12]
   [97,2]
   [100,9]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>110</s> 104 bytes

```
10:p010p&v>10g   >.@       |%g:0:<
`*:g:0:  <p:0+1g:0<p01+2g01<     |
0:g:*-   #v_10g1+v^        <     >
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYwxCoAwEAR7X3EgWiQoexYWRwi@REWI6SSNqfx7PIlbTTE7RzjvK4ZSGJLASH32jEhEflyo7umiQFyzG/mAyCWBZWWnFztFsKtiAzXMoNjmTTNs8/pHqCq@lBkv)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, <s>59</s> <s>61</s> 57 bytes

```
n=>1.to(n).map(i=>println(i,1.to(n).filter(i%_==0).size))
```

Comment: This seems to print out the results for all the numbers from 1 to 100.  Shouldn't it take input and calculate on the input?

Comment: @WheatWizard you are correct, I was mixing it up with https://code-golf.io/divisors#python, fixed.

Comment: It would also help to have a link to an online interpreter, like [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##PYzLCsIwEADv/YqlIOxCLGkFRTSFHj34B4LEGmWlbkOagw/67ZEKehxmmKG1nU396ebaCHvLAu4RnZwHaLyHdwaXPgAybOfQhGCfWKpKlZVaaLXUar1SpdZEUwg@sETEnUR3dSGJqcsi9ihU3K1HNvU36ARZ/cSFu@gC8uxojKZi4JcjSgCETLT5P/OD5BOO2Zg@). I'd edit one in myself, but don't know Scala, so haven't managed to actually invoke the lambda.

Comment: @UnrelatedString Thanks I'll make sure to include this in the future

Comment: Your earlier answer doesn't seem to be working, but [this](https://tio.run/##PcxLCsIwGEXheVdxKQgJREgqKNoHdOjAHQgSawKR8DekQXzQtUdFcHT4JmcatNd5PF/NkHDQjmDuydBlQh8CXsVNe9gd9pTQdr9kajuFNIJgnU8mMlqcGsUn9zS5tmMEc2iW6GPUD6ZEJVQlVlKspdhuhJKS888YCNFRYpY5zus/yyOVX87FnN8) should (27 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `L`, 1 byte

```
F
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0ko9S7IKlpSVpuhYL3ZYUJyUXQ3kLFhkbQFgA)

Or **2 bytes** flagless:

```
Fl
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi9xylhQnJRdDuQsWGRtAWAA)

`F` gets the list of all factors, and `l` gets the length.