# No. Of Factors Does the Number Have

Tags: code-golf, fastest-code, python, factoring

Create a function which takes in a input integer and then returns the number of factors it has, like if you pass `25` then it will return `3` since it has 3 factors i.e. `1,5,25`.
**Challenge:**
Make the fastest and the smallest code!

Comment: "Make the fastest and the smallest code" are incompatible. Since these can be odds, it's unclear how to measure tradeoffs in one versus the other. It's also not clear what "fastest" means without some benchmark. I'd suggest just keeping the shortest code part ([tag:code-golf]).

Comment: This is known as the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function).

Comment: [OEIS A000005](https://oeis.org/A000005)

Comment: Actually, looks like this is a duplicate of [Count the divisors of a number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64944/20260) for code golf.

Comment: what's the scoring criterion here? Is it fastest first, then shortest?

Comment: shortest first has different and fastest has different

Answer (score 3):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 1 byte

```
     # Get Divisor count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCXP@/zcyBQA)

Got to use Neim, yay.