# Calculate the Number, Divisors Edition

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

*Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1609248) over on Math.*

Let the prime factorization of a number, *n*, be represented as: \$P(n) = 2^a\times3^b\times5^c\times\cdots\$. Then the number of divisors of *n* can be represented as \$D(n) = (a+1)\times(b+1)\times(c+1)\times\cdots\$. Thus, we can easily say that the number of divisors of \$2n\$ is \$D(2n) =  (a+2)\times(b+1)\times(c+1)\times\cdots\$,
the number of divisors of \$3n\$ is \$D(3n) =  (a+1)\times(b+2)\times(c+1)\times\cdots\$,
and so on.

#### Challenge

Write a program or function that uses these properties to calculate \$n\$, given certain divisor inputs.

#### Input

A set of integers, let's call them \$w, x, y, z\$, with all of the following definitions:

- all inputs are greater than 1 -- \$w, x, y, z > 1\$
- \$x\$ and \$z\$ are distinct -- \$x\ne z\$
- \$x\$ and \$z\$ are prime -- \$P(x)=x, D(x)=2, P(z)=z \text{ and } D(z)=2\$
- \$w\$ is the number of divisors of \$xn\$ -- \$D(xn)=w\$
- \$y\$ is the number of divisors of \$zn\$ -- \$D(zn)=y\$

For the problem given in the linked question, an input example could be \$(28, 2, 30, 3)\$. This translates to \$D(2n)=28\$ and \$D(3n)=30\$, with \$n=864\$.

#### Output

A single integer, \$n\$, that satisfies the above definitions and input restrictions.  If multiple numbers fit the definitions, output the smallest. If no such integer is possible, output a [falsey](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/42963) value.

#### Examples:

```
(w, x, y, z) => output

(28, 2, 30, 3) => 864
(4, 2, 4, 5) => 3
(12, 5, 12, 23) => 12
(14, 3, 20, 7) => 0 (or some other falsey value)
(45, 13, 60, 11) => 1872
(45, 29, 60, 53) => 4176
```

#### Rules:

- Standard code-golf rules and [loophole restrictions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) apply.
- [Standard input/output rules](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1326/42963) apply.
- Input numbers can be in any order - please specify in your answer which order you're using.
- Input numbers can be in any suitable format: space-separated, an array, separate function or command-line arguments, etc. - your choice.
- Similarly, if output to STDOUT, surrounding whitespace, trailing newline, etc. are all optional.
- *Input parsing and output formatting are not the interesting features of this challenge.*
- In the interests of sane complexity and integer overflows, the challenge number \$n\$ will have restrictions such that \$1 < n < 100000\$ -- i.e., you don't need to worry about possible answers outside this range.

#### Related

- [Count the divisors of a number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64944/42963)
- [Give the smallest number that has N divisors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11080/42963)
- [Divisor sum from prime-power factorization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53550/42963)

Comment: So, if the smallest solution is larger than 100,000, I can choose to return either a solution or zero?

Comment: @Dennis If it makes your code shorter, sure. Either would be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
×€ȷ5R¤ÆDL€€Z=Ḅi3
```

This is a brute force solution that tries all possible values up to 100,000. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5figqzItzVSwqTDhkRM4oKs4oKsWj3huIRpMw&input=&args=Miwz+MjgsMzA)

#### Non-competing version

The latest version of Jelly has a bug fix that allows to golf down the above code to **15 bytes**.

```
ȷ5R×€³ÆDL€€=Ḅi3
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=yLc1UsOX4oKswrPDhkRM4oKs4oKsPeG4hGkz&input=&args=Miwz+MjgsMzA&debug=on)

#### How it works

```
×€ȷ5R¤ÆDL€€Z=Ḅi3  Main link. Left input: x,z. Right input: w,y

     ¤            Combine the two atoms to the left into a niladic chain.
  ȷ5              Yield 100,000 (1e5).
    R             Apply range. Yields [1, ..., 100,000].
x€                Multiply each r in the range by x and z.
                  This yields [[x, ..., 100,000x], [z, ..., 100,000z]].
      ÆD          Compute the divisors of each resulting integer.
        L€€       Apply length to each list of divisors.
                  This counts the divisors of each integer in the 2D array.
           Z      Zip; group the divisors of kx and kz in pairs.
            =     Compare each [divisors(kx), divisors(kz)] with [w, y].
                  This yields a pair of Booleans.
             Ḅ    Convert each Boolean pair from binary to integer.
              i3  Find the first index of 3. Yields 0 for not found.
```

Comment: Congrats, you win by default! :D